# Stack extends Vector

Tags: java, vector, stack

If stacks extends vector does that mean that stacks are syncronized?

Note from Vector Java docs

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is synchronized, but according to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) you should prefer a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) instead of a `Stack`.

From the [`Stack` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
>   provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should
>   be used in preference to this class. For example:
>
> `Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`

Comment: and in case of doubt [look into the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Stack.java) (*openjdk only ;))

Comment: why don't use LinkedList? ArrayDeque is an implementation of Deque, but Vector is an implementation of List

Answer (score 3):

Yes, methods inherited from Vector remain synchronized in Stack. Own Stack methods peek, pop, search are synchronized in Stack. Stack.push and Stack.empty methods are not synchronized, but

```
public boolean empty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

public E push(E item) {
    addElement(item);
    return item;
}
```

both methods are calling Vector's synchronized methods therefore Stack.empty and Stack.push are thread safe.

Comment: +1. I think this is correct. I don't think extending vector makes itself Stack synchronized. It is how methods are defined.

Comment: Right, it is not a class can be synchronzied but its methods